# Complex analysis: definition of cluster point

Tags: complex-analysis

Cluster point refers to a point where poles become ‘infinitely dense’. For example, $0$ is a cluster point of $\csc \frac1z$.

Recently I invented a definition of cluster point (because I don’t see any rigorous definition on the internet):

> Suppose $f$ admits an analytic continuation to $\mathbb C\setminus\{s_k\}$. $c$ is a cluster point iff $$\{z~|~0<|z-c|<r\}\cap\{s_k\}\ne\emptyset\qquad{\forall r>0}$$

I think this definition is not rigorous enough as it does not rule out the case of ‘natural boundaries’, as mentioned in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)).

So, what is the true definition of cluster point? And how can one rigorously use the true definition to prove $0$ is a cluster point of $\csc\frac1z$?

Comment: A cluster point is nothing but a [limit point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point): 'In mathematics, a limit point (or cluster point or accumulation point) of a set S in a topological space X is a point x that can be "approximated" by points of S in the sense that every neighbourhood of x with respect to the topology on X also contains a point of S other than x itself. A limit point of a set S does not itself have to be an element of S.'

Comment: @KennyLau How can this be rephrased for the case of complex analysis?